# How can I solve the simultaneous equations that arise in solving $\cos(z)=2$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If I have $\cos(z)=2$ I can say $\cos(a+ib)=2$

using double angle ideas $\cos(a)\cos(ib)+\sin(a)\sin(ib)=2$
using Euler's formula $\cos(a)\cosh(b)+i\sin(a)\sinh(b)=2$
equating real and imaginary parts $\cos(a)\cosh(b)=2$, $\sin(a)\sinh(b)=0$.

from here I'm unsure how to solve this set of simultaneous equations.

Comment: Do you have to use the trig, hyperbolig trig formulae? I think there's a more direct way.

Comment: I'm not sure but if I say that z=arccos(2) I end up with a purely real solution which makes me think that It's missing something?

Comment: If $\arccos 2$ is real, you have something wrong with your $\arccos$..

Comment: hmmm.. yes it actually gives an error. I must have done cos before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: A better way to do this.  $\cos z = (e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$.  Then your equation $\cos z = 2$ becomes a quadratic equation for $e^{iz}$.

Comment: so e^i2z-4e^iz+1=o and solve that?

Comment: ...so if you actually want real and imaginary parts in your answer, you will need to know how to do real and imaginary parts of the complex logarithm.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, as $\cos z = {1 \over 2} (e^{iz} + e^{-iz})$, setting this equal to $2$, and writing $w = e^{iz}$, we have

$${1 \over 2} (w + 1/w) = 2 \ \ \text{ or alternatively } w^2 + 1 = 4w$$

$w = 2 \pm \sqrt 3$. Now solve for $z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z=2+i\cdot\pm\sqrt{1-2^2}=2\pm\sqrt3$$

$$\implies iz=\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)\iff z=-i\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$$